# Firebase Crashlytics can't track an exception in my app

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, crashlytics

I am receiving this error via Firebase Crashlytics but there is no reference to my code in crash stack, how can I find the crash cause?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getHeight()' on a null object reference
android.widget.AbsListView$PositionScroller.run (AbsListView.java:7719)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:974)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:786)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:718)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:960)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6501)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: It obviously complains about `getHeight()` method. You better put a null check before using such code.

Comment: @Mohsen It's obviously in OS code, I can't edit it :)

Comment: Oh right. How about sharing some codes? And please mention about the Android version you're tesing on and any other helpful information.